# Is there a way to get bucket name in Firebase functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I have been looking around for the ways to retrieve the bucket name in Firebase functions.

The documentation says you can do something like:

```
functions.storage.bucket("bucket_name").object()...
```

However, in all examples I have seen the "bucket name" is hard-coded. In my project, images are stored in the buckets named as user-ids. So when a write event is triggered, I want to retrieve this user id. Is there a way to do it? Something like this (below)?

```
exports.optimizeImages = functions.storage.bucket("{uid}").object().onFinalize(async (object) => {

const uid = ???
...
})
```

Comment: I don't understand - what has to be dynamic about it?  Are you saying you don't know which bucket to use at the time the function is deployed?  Or are you saying you want to know which bucket triggered the function?  Please edit the question to be more specific.

Comment: I'm still not clear.  Are you saying that you want to this function respond to changes in multiple buckets using a wildcard?  Or are you saying that you've already registered the function on multiple buckets, and you want to figure out which bucket triggered the function?

Comment: @OlgaPp Can you add a screenshot of your Cloud Storage bucket(s) and an example of path for the userId file you upload to this bucket.

Comment: @DougStevenson, imagine I have a bucket {uid}. In it I have a folder, e.g. "raw". Assume I only want this function to trigger if the event is coming from {uid}/raw, but not from {uid}/compressed. Is it possible? It seems like I can find the bucket name by string-splitting the object.bucket property by "/" (this was my original question). But a more general question is, as you said, "figure out which bucket (and folder) triggered the function".

Answer (score 2):

When you declare a storage trigger, you are only attaching it to a single bucket.  If you want to trigger on multiple buckets, you have to declare multiple triggers.  As such, each trigger function should always know which bucket it was fired for - you can simply hard coding it in the function implementation (it will be the same as what you specified in the function builder - just reuse that value).

If you must share the exact same function implementation with multiple triggers on multiple buckets, you can certainly parse the [`object.bucket`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_storage_.objectmetadata#bucket) property. That seems like a decent way to go.